# Pass by reference vs. Pass by pointer: Boost threads and deadline timer

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, timer

I have this simple program that outputs increasing integers in the span of 1 second using boost libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace std;


void func1(bool* done)
{
    float i=0;
    while (!(*done))
    {
        cout << i << " ";
        i++;
    }
    return;
}

void timer(bool* done, boost::thread* thread)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    timer.wait();
    *done = true;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    bool done = false;

    boost::thread thread1(func1, &done);
    boost::thread thread2(timer, &done, &thread1);
    thread2.join();
    thread1.join();
}
```

That iteration of the code works, however I had originally had the bool defined in the main function passed by reference into functions func1 and thread. i.e.:

```
void func1(bool& done) /*...*/ while (!(done))
/* ... */
void timer(bool& done, boost::thread* thread) /*...*/ done = true;
```

with thread definitions:

```
    boost::thread thread1(func1, done);
    boost::thread thread2(timer, done, &thread1);
```

When I execute it like that, the loop within func1() never terminates! I've added a breakpoint at the return of timer(), and my IDE (MS VC++ express 2010) indicates that bool done indeed has a value of true, even within func1().

Any insight as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass argument by reference, use `boost:ref`:

`boost::thread thread1(func1, boost::ref(done));`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think EITHER of your solutions are valid, because they are not using "atomic" type or some other mechanism to ensure that the `done` is kept in sync.

The reason one works and the other doesn't is probably the way that compilers deal with pointers vs. references when deciding when & where in the function it needs to reload the value of `done`. But in theory, there's nothing stopping the compiler from looping forever if `done` is false on the first iteration, in either case.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor

> Thread Constructor with arguments
>
> template  thread(F f,A1 a1,A2 a2,...);
>
> Preconditions:
>
> ```
> F and each An must by copyable or movable.  Effects:
>
> As if thread(boost::bind(f,a1,a2,...)). Consequently, f and each an are copied into internal storage for access by the new thread.
> ```

The key word here is "copied".  The variable done in main, func1 and timer all refer to different addresses, which is why setting done true in timer does not end func1's loop.

I assume the reason it works with the *done is because it is copying the address, thus it would be the same across the functions.